# I need to export a sql table into a pipe delimited text file including the column names as well using python

Tags: python, mysql, unix, text-files, delimiter

I am currently using the below and it imports the data which is comma seperated without the column names.

Also, there is a problem with the dates in the table, as it returns all the dates columns as "datetime.date(1925, 1, 24)", where the actual date in the table is like "1925-01-24".

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'username', passwd = 'password', port = port, db = 'DBNAME')
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = """SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable;"""
cursor.execute(query)

FILE = cursor.fetchall()

with open('FILE.txt', 'w') as f:
    for row in cursor:
    f.write("%s\n" % str(row))
```

Comment: in the title you say pipe in the body you say comma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use python at all?

```
SELECT 'column name1', 'column name2' 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM myschema.mytable INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/mytable.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
```

Just type this in the mysql console. Note if you get an error in this query saying something about secure file privilages do

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```

And then use the specified location instead of '/tmp' in the previous query.

Comment: I do not get the column names using this

Comment: One small doubt, I am getting \N for null values, is there a way I can get blanks in case of nulls?

Comment: select col1, col2, coalesce(col_with_nulls,''), other col from mytable